# Join where 2 time periods intersect

Tags: mysql, cross-join

We have 2 tables, and are trying to figure out how to do a cross join where 2 time periods intersect.

The first table (`employment`) contains 4 columns:

```
EmployerID, UserID, StartDate, EndDate
```

The second table (`status_history`) also contains 4 columns:

```
UserID, Status, StartDate, EndDate
```

`employment` table contains records showing which "job" each user was associated with, and for how long (StartDate and EndDate). Similarly, `status_history` contains records showing whether the user was Active / Inactive (employed, or unemployed) - also with StartDate and EndDate.

We are trying to build a view that would create a proper "cross join" between the two tables.

```
EmployerID, UserID, Status, StartDate, EndDate
```

I tried creating an SQL Fiddle, but for some reason, I'm getting an error from them. So, I have provided the Schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE employment
    (`EmployerID` int, `UserID` int, `StartDate` date, `EndDate` date);

CREATE TABLE status_history
    (`UserID` int, `Status` varchar(10), `StartDate` date, `EndDate` date);

INSERT INTO employment
    (`EmployerID`, `UserID`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`)
VALUES
    (123, 111, '2017-01-01', '2017-03-04'),
    (345, 111, '2017-03-04', '2017-03-07'),
    (567, 111, '2017-03-07', '2017-04-10'),
    (789, 111, '2017-04-10', NULL)
;

INSERT INTO status_history
    (`UserID`, `Status`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`)
VALUES
    (111, 'Active', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-17'),
    (111, 'Inactive', '2017-02-17', '2017-03-02'),
    (111, 'Active', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-09'),
    (111, 'Inactive', '2017-03-09', NULL),
;
```

Based on the data, I want to retrieve following rows:

```
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| EmployerID |  UserID |   Status  |  StartDate  |   EndDate   |
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|        123 |     111 |  Active   |  2017-01-01 |  2017-02-17 |
|        123 |     111 |  Inactive |  2017-02-17 |  2017-03-02 |
|        123 |     111 |  Active   |  2017-03-02 |  2017-03-04 |
|        345 |     111 |  Active   |  2017-03-04 |  2017-03-07 |
|        567 |     111 |  Active   |  2017-03-07 |  2017-03-09 |
|        567 |     111 |  Inactive |  2017-03-09 |  2017-04-10 |
|        789 |     111 |  Inactive |  2017-04-10 |  NULL       |
+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Any help shall be appreciated!

Comment: use inner join. show what you tried?

Comment: We had tried a few things, none of which gave us the correct result. The latest query was a simple INNER JOIN from `status_history` to `employment` `ON sh.UserID = e.UserID AND sh.StartDate = e.StartDate AND sh.EndDate = e.EndDate`

Comment: which one of them is unique `EmployerID` or `UserID` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with the query, I was able to figure out the answer.

It turns out the answer is quite simple: I got the result by doing a join on `UserID` where the time period intersects (i.e. `StartDate` from `employment` < `EndDate` from `status_history` and `EndDate` from `employment` > `StartDate` from `status_history`. For the edge case of NULL EndDate, I use today's date.

Then, I simply select the GREATEST of the two StartDate, and LEAST of the two EndDate.